# How to load initial store data through meta tag before redux sagas are complete?

Tags: javascript, metadata, redux, redux-saga

Currently, I'm running into a situation where a server rendered page is loaded prior to sagas completing which populate the store. However, elements such as `links` are dependent on the store in order to fire an action. e.g. `login link` would need to change that state of the application to show a modal, but doesn't have access to the store data yet. I would like to load the initial store immediately through a `meta tag`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you actually need. If i understand you right, you just need to wait when all sagas are done then render markup on the server. You can achieve this by wrapping server side sagas in saga-wrapper and then run it through middleware API:

```
sagaMiddleware.run().done.then(...) <- regular Promise
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did end up solving it. Thank you!